# How to disable Leaflet layers control?

Tags: leaflet, layers

I need to disable L.control.layers when user click's on a certain button and enable when it click's on a seccond button.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do it using CSS.

Select the layer control using its class *leaflet-control-layers*:

```
var lc = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-layers');
```

And then hide it:

```
lc[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

or show it:

```
lc[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

---

In case you are using jQuery:

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers').hide();
```

and:

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers').show();
```

Comment: Great idea!. It's good solution and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the value returned by `L.control.layers(...)`:

```js
var controls = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays, options).addTo(map);
```

Now you can call `map.removeControl(controls);` and if you should want to add them back in again later on: `map.addControl(controls);`